# Is python dict insertion order preserved after deleting elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744) says python dicts keep insertion order of keys as of python 3.7.  The comments to that answer discuss the implementation details of what happens when a key is deleted.  I'd like to know: what does the language spec guarantee about key order in the face of deletes (preferably with a link)?

Based on the discussion, I bet it guarantees insertion order of the undeleted elements, but I've been unable to find confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language guarantees that undeleted elements will remain in the same order after a key is deleted.

The [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) states (emphasis mine):

> Dictionaries preserve insertion order, meaning that **keys will be produced in the same order they were added sequentially over the dictionary**. Replacing an existing key does not change the order, however removing a key and re-inserting it will add it to the end instead of keeping its old place.

The bolded text would not be true if the order of keys changed after a deletion.